# Is it possible to set the host's playback device with VirtualBox?

Tags: windows, audio, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox version *4.3.12r93733* on a Windows 7 host with a Windows 7 guest, and I'm wondering if it's possible to change the audio playback device for VirtualBox on the host?

It doesn't matter if it's a global setting for all VMs. I have an M-Audio Audiophile 2496 sound card, and I'm wanting to run the sound from VirtualBox VMs through my motherboard's audio interface.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual box uses default audio device on the host so you can make it your default audio device. However if you need to install very specific software for it to work you will need to pass the PCI device down to the guest. This will depend on your motherboard and it's support for this thing called IOMMU. Typically Intel server grade boards have this (not sure if Intel calls it IOMMU) and some AMD consumer grade boards have support. If you have Gigabyte or Asus motherboard with 970/990 chipset it is very likely that you can enable it in BIOS.

Anyway start with Wikipedia article on IOMMU to get better understanding of what it is, and then figure out if your board supports it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wanting the VM to play through a non-default playback device, separate to everything else.

It's not really massively important, but it would be useful.

My motherboard's chipset is 990FX/SB950, but I'll have a look in the BIOS anyway, and read about IOMMU.